# could not find or load main class org.tesng.TestNG

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I am using testng-6.8.21.jar for writing test case from the following link:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_tutorial.pdf

I am able to compile the java file `TestNGSimpleTest.java`

but when I try to use this command:

```
java -cp "C:\TestNG_WORKSPACE" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

it says:

> could not find or load main class org.tesng.TestNG

Comment: You must add the test-ng lib to the classpath. You could do it easier with Maven for example.

Comment: I have added the testng jar to classpath .could you please let me know still what i am doing wrong

Comment: I am not used to add manually jars in command line. I think that you must not only give some directories but full path to the jars. Try : `java -cp "C:\TestNG_WORKSPACE/*.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml` (if your testng.jar is in the `TestNG_WORKSPACE`)

Comment: Worked for me (but complains about another missing jar). I will post an answer with maven :)

Comment: where did u keep your jar file .please tell me.. For me it doesn't worked at all

Comment: If I place the testng jar (`testng-6.8.8.jar` in my case)+ `testng.xml` + java classes in one directory (bad practice but easier to explain) then this command line `java -cp 'testng-6.8.8.jar' org.testng.TestNG testng.xml` finds TestNG's main class but complains about other missing classes (I am writing an answer which explains it)

Comment: thanks .I am looking forward eagerly for your answer.

Comment: "org.tesng.TestNG" There is a typo in both the report and the question title... Did you copy/paste or rewrote this? Because if you copy/pasted, you probably actually typed something wrong in the `java` command!

Answer (score 0):

You must provide full path to the jars in the classpath. For example :

```
java -cp '/path/to/testng-6.8.8.jar' org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

But `testng` requires other dependencies that you also must include in the classpath :

```
\- org.testng:testng:jar:6.1.1:test
   +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
   +- org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:test
   +- com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.12:test
   \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.6:test
```

The easiest way is to use a dependency manager. For example, Maven.

Briefly, you need (not required but it makes everything easier) to have a standard project structure :

```
main-directory
  pom.xml <- File required by maven. It always has this name.
  -src
    -main
      -java <- Place your Java classes here
      -resources <- Place your images, conf files here etc.
    -test
      -java <- Place your java test classes here
      -resources <- Place your test resources here.
```

Then, with this simple `pom.xml`, Maven understand that you want testng and downloads testNG's dependencies :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app-name</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <!-- Declare your dependencies here-->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Then launch :

```
mvn test
```

And if you want to have a view on the dependencies, use :

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

(This is how I got the preceding dependency tree)

Comment: Yes. Having the initial project structure can be hard if you do it manually but your favorite IDE (IntelliJ / Eclipse / Netbeans) probably has some built-in functionnality to create it. There is also a maven command for that.

Comment: I am able to resolve that missing jar exception but i am getting error as cannot find classpath for TestNGSimpleTest, can u give some light on this